# Intuition about definition of projective line and relation to the sphere

Tags: geometry, soft-question, projective-geometry

I have a definition of the projective line given in my lecture notes as:

$ \mathbb{P}^1=(\mathbb{C}^2 $ \ $ \{0\})/\mathbb{C}^\times $

my notes then state that this is the space of lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and is isomorphic to the Riemann Sphere.

I can imagine how the space of lines through the origin is isomorphic to the Riemann sphere, however I cannot see/imagine from the definition given above of $ \mathbb{P}^1 $ how this definition corresponds to the space of lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Is there a good way to see this directly from the definition as given? Or a good way to visualise this definition that makes it easier?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem might be that the notion here is one of **complex** lines through the origin. Such a line consists of all points $c (z, w)$, where $(z, w)$ is a fixed non-origin point in $\Bbb C^2$, and $c$ ranges over the **complex** numbers. So a complex line "looks just like" a real plane.

The definition you were given says to take all non-origin pairs $(z, w)$ and declare two of them "equal" if one is a multiple of the other. So if our pairs are 
$(z_1, w_1)$ and $(z_2, w_2)$, and they're "equal" then there's some non-zero complex number $c$ with 
$$
c(z_1, w_1) = (z_2, w_2),
$$
which exactly says that $(z_2, w_2)$ is on the line spanned by $(z_1, w_1)$.

As for the correspondence with $S^2$, that's not so bad either. For any point 
$$
(z, w) \in \Bbb C^2
$$
you can say that it's "the same" (i.e., on the same complex line through the origin as) the point
$$
(\frac{z}{w}, 1)
$$
by picking $c = 1/w$. (This fails if $w = 0$ --- more on that in a moment.)

Thus for (almost) each complex line through the origin, we get a pair 
$$
(q, 1)
$$
where $q$ is a complex number. And for each complex number $q$, there's an associated line spanned by $(q, 1)$. So the set of "almost all lines-through-the-origin-in-$\Bbb C^2$" corresponds in a 1-1 way to $\Bbb C$.

There's exactly one complex line we haven't handled by this method --- the one spanned by $(1, 0)$. And that one ends up corresponding to the "point at infinity", so that we get the whole Riemann sphere.  (To make sense of this, there's some work to do: you have to show that lines closer and closer to the span of $(1, 0)$ correspond to points of the complex plane that are farther and farther from the origin, so that the span of $(1, 0)$ really does correspond to a 'point at infinity', but that's actually not too difficult.)

Comment: thank you so much for your really detailed answer, that really helped me make sense of what the definition was saying. As a slight aside I think a part of my confusion was to do with the two slashes going different ways, do these mean two separate things in this case or are they both 'modding out'?

Comment: The first says "$\Bbb C^2$, but throw away  $(z, w) = (0, 0)$ (which is oddly written just $0$)." In general, $A \ B$ means all of $A$ except the stuff in $B$, which is why the $0$ is in set-brackets, although people sometimes omit these, alas. The second, which is a forward slash, says "take equivalence classes under an equivalence relation", in this case the relation being "differ by multiplication by a nonzero complex number". Of course, $C^{\times}$ isn't an equivalence relation, it's a set. But the set acts on $\Bbb C^2$ in an "obvious" way to define an equivalence relation. Sigh.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for. You've really helped me.

Comment: In the second sentence of my comment above, $A \ B$ should have been $A \setminus B$; sorry for the typo. Glad the comment helped otherwise.